# Could not decode based64-encoded string by System.Convert.ToBase64String

Tags: ios, objective-c, decode, encode

I am encountering an issue about based64 encode/decode for an image.

My iOS client downloads a string, which is a `based64-encoded` image on the server side by an API named `System.Convert.ToBase64String.(dotnet)`

However, some pictures could not be decoded on the client side by  `NSData.initWithBase64EncodedString`. It always returns nil.

I have tried the same `based64-encoded` string on Android and some tools on the web, all works fine.

I have no idea how to debug this issue to figure out which byte causes this problem.

Any idea?

Comment: You will need to use python, or some other scripting language, to download the stream, decode it from base-64 to binary and save it to file.  Then use the `file` command, under OSX, to attempt to determine what sort of file it is and then discover if iOS supports it.  Either that or you have a bug in your code (more likely), but without seeing it, who knows?

Comment: Thanks for kinda hint, you are right. trojanfoe. I have downloaded stream and comparing the stream App got byte by byte.  yes there is bug in my code.